# Why is the formset content not updated after POST?

Tags: django, forms

I am using a formset to display forms to the user and update my database. Upon success, I would like to immediately redisplay the formset with the updated (added/removed) data and an extra empty form.

The database update is done properly. If the extra form is filled, it is displayed back. But deleted forms (rows) are still displayed after a submit, and if the extra form was filled with data, no new extra form is made available after submit.

Here is my `view.py` code:

```
@login_required
def user_setting(request):
    user = request.user
    OnlineFormSet = modelformset_factory(Online, 
                                         can_delete=True,
                                         extra=1)

    onlines = Online.objects.filter(user=user).order_by('start')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = OnlineFormSet(request.POST, queryset=onlines)
        if formset.is_valid():
            for q in formset.save(commit=False):
                q.user=user
                q.save()
    else:
        formset = OnlineFormSet(queryset=onlines)

    context['online_formset'] = formset

    return response(request, context)
```

I also tried to use a redirect at the end of `if request.method == 'POST'` block, but without success.

Is it possible to have a brand new formset containing all the data that has just been submitted/deleted as a result of the POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I solved this...

First there was an error in the template, where I had `action=""` which I changed to `action="."`

```
<form id="online" method="post" action=".">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ online_formset }}
<input id="online-submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I updated the `view.py` code so it will re-create a formset based on the same queryset even if a POST occured before (and hence a save).

I used `Online.objects.all()` when creating the formset upon POST instead of the `onlines` queryset restricted to my user.

```
@login_required
def user_setting(request):
    user = request.user
    OnlineFormSet = modelformset_factory(Online, can_delete=True,extra=1) 
    onlines = Online.objects.filter(user=user).order_by('start')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = OnlineFormSet(request.POST, queryset=Online.objects.all())
        if formset.is_valid():
            for q in formset.save(commit=False):
                q.user=user
                q.save()
    formset = OnlineFormSet(queryset=onlines)
    context['online_formset'] = formset
    return response(request, context)
```

This way, I always get a fresh formset right after it was updated.

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with your code: if the form is not valid, no errors can be shown in the template because you are re-initializing the form before passing it to the renderer.

Good web citizens always redirect after a successful POST (this prevents the "confirm form submission" prompt when refreshing the page, amongst others). The code I'd use is:

```
@login_required
def user_setting(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = OnlineFormSet(request.POST, queryset=Online.objects.all())
        if formset.is_valid():
            for q in formset.save(commit=False):
                q.user=user
                q.save()
            return redirect(reverse('user-settings')) # Redirect to this view on success
    else:
        formset = OnlineFormSet(queryset=onlines)
    context['online_formset'] = formset
    return response(request, context)
```

PS Are you sure redirecting after a successful POST doesn't work? It does work with the code above.